# Visual Studio 2015 - Can't create Windows 10 app packages for the Windows Store

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, win-universal-app, windows-store

Since I installed Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 I can't create any app packages for the Windows Store anymore. The apps are linked to the store and compile without any mistakes, however every time I try to create a store package it fails because "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.NetNative\x86\ilc\Tools\nutc_driver.exe" returns exit code -1073740791. I've already tried both repairing and reinstalling Visual Studio, I've also reinstalled every single Windows 10 SDK package (10240 as well as 10586.212), but none of these attempts fixed my problem. It doesn't even work with a completely new, empty project.

The weird thing is that I can create packages not linked to the store without any problems, the problem only occurs when I try to create the actual store packages.

I'm running the latest **stable** release of Windows 10 Pro x64 (10586.212) and **never** tried the Preview SDK or other sorts of pre-release things with these packages. Also, they're all located on my main partition (C:).

The next thing I'd do is to reinstall Windows 10, however that can't be the only option to fix this issue (supposing it would do). So is there anybody who knows what exactly causes Visual Studio to fail at this point?

Thanks!

Edit: The error is also specified as "ILT0005".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've figured out what had caused Visual Studio to fail. Believe it or not - the display language of Visual Studio was the problem. I changed the language from German into English and everything worked just fine afterwards.

However, thanks anyway. And maybe I can reach and help some other people who are struggling with the same bug.